# Having additional dot(.) when I try to read from .txt and formatting into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to read a set of data from .txt file,

which looks like this (By the way, the original data comes from the excel, and then it copied into the .txt file).

> 

```
0.789   0.439   0.440
0.792   0.440   0.456
0.797   0.432   0.449
```

and then I use

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, '\t')
```

to read the file.

```
        df.loc[-1] = df.columns
        df.index = df.index + 1  # shifting index
        df.sort_index(inplace=True)
        df = df.astype(float)
```

then I'm trying to change the type of the data which I read previously into float.
This is where I got an error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.439.1'

Which is very weird, because I don't have such data anywhere.
I can't help but to think that dot is generated somewhere in the source code.

Oddly enough, when I try different set of data it works.

Please help me. I have no clue.

I look for the weird data in case I did a mistake or whatnot, I found nothing.

Comment: You could open a python shell then write a for loop to read every line. Then `if "0.439" in line: print(repr(line))`. Now you have potentially messed up lines. If one looks odd, that's your guy. You could also search for "0.439.1" in the dataframe `for index, row in df.iterrows(): do the check` which would give you the bad line in the .txt. The idea is to see if you've got bad data in the .txt file.

Comment: You could perform a validation step before running your parser code. Use regex to make sure there is only one point in the float, and if there is a validation error. Then handle the validation error.. 
E.g. by omitting the float in question, or through a validation error and stop the parsing action.

Comment: Do you have a header? The command should be `df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None)`, the extra `.1` is typical of column names deduplication.

Comment: @mozway You're right! I added 'header=None' as you mentioned and it works. I never new anything like presence of header or deduplication stuff. Thank you so much! I want to make your comment as the 'official answer' but I'm not sure it's possible. If you have spare time please post the answer for this post and I'll make it as an official answer.

Comment: @Cornell sure, answer added ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.1` is typical of column names deduplication. This means that part of your data is handled as header.

Use `header=None` to avoid this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None)
```